# I need my byte compression looked, I don't think it is compressing to where I wanted

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, byte

I'm trying to compress the byte data from video, the app crashes when the file is over 10mb due to the limitations of Parse servers. So I'm trying to compress at 10mb. The code does well on older phones but on the newer phones the the video bytes easily go over 10mb but the code won't compress the bytes down to 10 mb. Is there something I can add or something?

```
private void uploadVideo() {

    Intent videoIntent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

    mMediaUri = getOutputMediaFileUri (MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
    if (mMediaUri == null) {

        // display an error
        Toast.makeText (MemberActivity.this, R.string.error_external_storage,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
    } else {


        videoIntent.putExtra (MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mMediaUri);
        videoIntent.putExtra (MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 10);
        videoIntent.putExtra (MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, 1024*1024*10);
        videoIntent.putExtra (MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0); // 0 = lowest res
        startActivityForResult (videoIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    String mediaBytes = mMediaUri.getEncodedPath ();
        //Set up video file and data
        File iFile = new File (mediaBytes);
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[(int) iFile.length ()];

        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream (iFile);
            fileInputStream.read (byteArray);
            for (byte aByteArray : byteArray) {
                System.out.print ((char) aByteArray);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println ("File Not Found.");
            e.printStackTrace ();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            System.out.println ("Error Reading The File.");
            e1.printStackTrace ();
        }

        final ParseFile file = new ParseFile ("HipkuVideo.mp4", byteArray);
        file.saveInBackground (new SaveCallback () {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {

                    //addPhotoTransferToUserUpload (file);
                    // Show a simple toast message
                    Toast.makeText (MemberActivity.this, "Saving to SD Card",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();

                } else {

                    // Show a simple toast message
                    Toast.makeText (MemberActivity.this, "Error saving:" + e.getMessage (),

                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();

                }
```

and here is the compress code:

```
 public static byte[] getByteArrayFromFile(Context context, Uri uri) {
    byte[] fileBytes = null;
    InputStream inStream = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = null;

    if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
        try {
            inStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            // Compressor with highest level of compression
            Deflater compressor = new Deflater();
            compressor.setLevel(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION);

            // Give the compressor the data to compress
            compressor.setInput(fileBytes);
            compressor.finish();

            // Create an expandable byte array to hold the compressed data.
            // It is not necessary that the compressed data will be smaller than
            // the uncompressed data.
            outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(fileBytes.length);

            // Compress the data
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024*1024*10];
            while (!compressor.finished()) {
                int count = compressor.deflate(buf);
                outStream.write(buf, 0, count);
            }
            try {
                outStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            // Get the compressed data
            byte[] compressedData = outStream.toByteArray();

            byte[] bytesFromFile = new byte[1024]; // buffer size (1 MB)
            int bytesRead = inStream.read(compressedData);
            while (bytesRead != -1) {
                outStream.write(compressedData, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead = inStream.read(compressedData);
            }

            fileBytes = outStream.toByteArray();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            try {
                inStream.close();
                outStream.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) { /*( Intentionally blank */ }
        }
    }
    else {
        try {
            File file = new File(uri.getPath());
            FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
            fileBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(fileInput);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    return fileBytes;
}
```

Comment: I doubt that compressing an mp4 with deflate compression will do much good.

Comment: I can see that I'm trying to find another option.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compress further than what's provided by ZLIB, take a look at [Apache Commons Compress](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/examples.html).  Specifically, the section on XZ since that uses the LZMA compression algorithm which at it's highest level gives some of the best compression ratios around.  Be sure to thoroughly test performance however since it can get a little slow.  If you're worried about space you can cut out the Apache middleman and go straight to the [Tukaani](http://tukaani.org/xz/xz-javadoc/) java library for the same.